# How to extract all email headers and only the headers from an mbox (email) file containing many emails?

Tags: linux, bash, email, command-line, mbox

How can one extract *all* email headers and *only* the headers from an [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) (email) file containing many emails?

Answer (score 2):

The following generates `header.XXXX` files in `output_dir` on a per-email basis for every email found in the provided `mbox_file`:

1. [`git mailsplit -ooutput_dir mbox_file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mailsplit)
2. `cd output_dir`
3. `get_headers.sh`

`get_headers.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# formail(1) is part of the procmail package

for filename in *; do
    formail -X '' < "$filename"  > "header.$filename"
done
```

Tested with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)-ed `procmail` on a [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) 52.9.1 (64-bit) mbox file all running in:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G5033
$
```